# Iso-lines to 3D Surface Generation

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

I have a set of isolines points ( or contour points) such as this:

[image]

Each point has their own respective X, Y and Z. Since they are isolines, that means that all of the points will have a unique X-Y pair, i.e., they will be no two points with the same X and Y but different Z.

Now, is there any algorithm, or any software packages ( either in C# or matlab) that I can use to interpolate this isoline points into full 3D surface points?

P/S: I am not just interested in the final output, I am interested in getting the interpolated lines myself so that I can plot the surface myself.

Comment: @quid, I've fixed the problem

Comment: Thanks, that's great! (I already removed my earlier comment to avoid clutter and will come back to remove that one too in a while.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See these papers:

- W. Barrett, E. Mortensen, and D. Taylor.
  An image space algorithm for morphological contour interpolation.
  In Proceedings of Graphics Interface'94, pages 16-24, 1994.
- M. B. Gousie and W. R. Franklin.
  [Converting Elevation Contours to a Grid](http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/p/89-vancouver-sdh98-contour-gousie.pdf).
  In SDH’98, 1998.
  (See also 
  http://www.ecse.rpi.edu/~wrf/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Research/Research#toc8.)

If you can read (or guess) Portuguese, see

- [Uma Metodologia para Geração de Modelos de Elevação a partir de Curvas de Nível](http://w3.impa.br/~rbs/geoinfo2000/), 2000
- [Interpolação de Curvas de Nível por Difusão de Calor](http://w3.impa.br/~rbs/geoinfo2001/), 2001